# How to load image from API and save it into sqlite database?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm already get images into my recycle view. All the other details were saved into sqlite database. But there is a problem with saving image.

this is my database table and method for save details into data base

`val CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME " +
                "($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $BOOK_NAME TEXT, $DESCRIPTION TEXT, $AUTHOR TEXT, $COVER_PAGE BLOB, $ISBN TEXT, $LANGUAGE TEXT, $NUMBER_OF_PAGES INTEGER, $PRICE TEXT, $CATEGORY TEXT)"
        db?.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)`

```
fun addFavouriteBooks(
        id: Int,
        bookName: String,
        description: String,
        author: String,
        cover: ByteArray,
        isbn: String,
        language: String,
        numbOfPages: Int,
        price: String,
        category: String
    ): Long {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(ID, id)
        contentValues.put(BOOK_NAME, bookName)
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION, description)
        contentValues.put(AUTHOR, author)
        contentValues.put(COVER_PAGE, cover)
        contentValues.put(ISBN, isbn)
        contentValues.put(LANGUAGE, language)
        contentValues.put(NUMBER_OF_PAGES, numbOfPages)
        contentValues.put(PRICE, price)
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY, category)

        val res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)
        db.close()
        return res
    }
```

Here is my function in recycle adapter to catch the data in recycle view and sed it to the sqlite database. I haven't any idea to send image like other details.

```
        holder.like.setOnClickListener {
            var c_id = holder.id
            var c_name = holder.name.text.toString()
            var c_description = holder.description
            var c_author = holder.author.text.toString()
            var c_cover = holder.cover.toString()

            //i want to convert this c_cover into byte array

            var c_isbn = holder.isbn
            var c_lang = holder.language
            var c_numberOfPages: Int = holder.numbOfPages.toInt()
            var c_price = holder.price.text.toString()
            var c_category = holder.category

            var favList: Long = dbHelper.addFavouriteBooks(c_id.toInt(), c_name, c_description, c_author,c_cover, c_isbn, c_lang, c_numberOfPages, c_price, c_category)

            if(favList > 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Book added to favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

Comment: first you get the bitmap of your image then convert it to byte[]

Comment: can u send me the code for that conversion? I tried several methods but not working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kotlin yet. I'll send the code in java

Answer (score 1):

This how we do it in java.

```
byte[] Imagebyte = getBitmapAsByteArray(((BitmapDrawable) YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
```

Then we store it in sqlite in FIELD's with data type BLOB.

Comment: thank you. If you are not familiar with kotlin yet you can use  [java kotlin converter](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt)